# Need to extract the state and country name based on the city name extracted using python

Tags: python, api, location, response, country

```
    response = requests.get("https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries")
    json_response = response.json()

    countries = []
    for country in json_response['data']:
        countries.append(country['country'])

    cities = []
    for city in json_response['data']:
        cities.append(city['cities'])

    citys = []
    for sublist in cities:
        for item in sublist:
            citys.append(item)


    states = ['states list']

    places = GeoText(str_text)

    city = places.cities

    place_entity = locationtagger.find_locations(text = str_text)

    state = place_entity.regions

    country = places.countries

    for i in country:
        if i in countries:
           break

    for c in city:
        if c in citys:
            break

    for s in state:
        if s in states:
            break

    country_resu = list(i for i in country if i in countries)
    country_result = list(set(country_resu))
    if len(country_result) == 0:
        country_resu = "NA"
        country_result = country_resu

    city_resu = list(c for c in city if c in citys)
    city_result = list(set(city_resu))
    if len(city_result) == 0:
        city_resu = "NA"
        city_result = city_resu

    state_resu = list(s for s in state if s in states)
    state_result = list(set(state_resu))
    if len(state_resu) == 0:
        state_res = "NA"
        state_result = state_res

    output = [
        {"Location": {"City": city_result, "State": state_result, "Country": country_result}},]
```

I need to automatically extract the country if I extract the city or state from the text. And the same for state If I extract the city I need to automatically extract the state.

For example if I extract the city **"Chennai"** in city field automatically I need to fill the state **"Tamil Nadu"** and country **"India"** in the respective state and country field.

I had stuck on this and can't able to figure out the way to get the output. Kindly help me to solve the issue.

**Note**: For country and city Iam getting the data from a free api available online, and for state I inputted the states in a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by using geopy library in python

This is the link to the documentation [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

To solve your problem I would create a function that takes the list containing the country

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def read_country(city):
    """
    Convert cities and returns the country
    """
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="google") #user agent can be any user agent 
    location = geolocator.geocode(city, language="en") #specified the language as some countries are in other lanaguages
    country= location.address.split(',')[-1] #split the string based on comma and retruns the last element (country)
    return country
```

Then I would create a for loop to take ech city in the list and use the function created previously

```
#creating a loop to convert all cities to their respective countries and store in a list
    comp_location_country =[] #using list to preserve the order for the data frame

    for city in comp_location: #comp_location will be your list
        city_country = read_country(city)
        comp_location_country.append(city_country)
    print()
    print(comp_location_country)
```

Please like this if it helped you